# slack integration with api

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm trying to communicate slack with my application using https://api.slack.com/interactive-messages documentation.
I'm facing one issue while trying to send interactive message from slack to my-app. 
Here is my app.
https://gitlab.com/sureshgoud9999/slack-api-test.git

I've placed one "/api/messages" end-point of "POST" method to respond for interactive messages from slack,
here is the flow,

[oauth-route.js](https://gitlab.com/sureshgoud9999/slack-api-test/blob/master/server/api/oauth/route/oauth-route.js)
[oauth-dao.js](https://gitlab.com/sureshgoud9999/slack-api-test/blob/master/server/api/oauth/dao/oauth-dao.js)

Even though, I added bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }) in server.js file, it is not redirecting the request to proper method. Message deliver is failed while clicking on any buttons from slack.

Please help me out if I'm missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with URL-encoder. Its solved now.

Comment: cool. would be great if you could specify in more detail how it was solved and then mark your answer as solution. Ty!

Answer (score 0):

@ErikKalkoken 
Here are the tutorials mentioned,
https://api.slack.com/tutorials/tags/slack-apps
https://api.slack.com/tutorials/intro-to-message-buttons

passing urlencoder to the endpoint was not proper,

```
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
app.post('/slack/slash-commands/send-me-buttons', urlencodedParser, (req, res) =>{ ...}
```